# Suppress output of shell script

Tags: shell-script

I'm running this line on my shell script

```
sudo npm install -g yaml-cli -y 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

I would expect to get no output, but I still get

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirections are evaluated from left to right, you have got this other way around. Just swap the redirections:

```
sudo npm install -g yaml-cli -y >/dev/null 2>&1
```

In `sudo npm install -g yaml-cli -y 2>&1 >/dev/null`:

- First, for `2>&1`, the STDERR (FD 2) is being sent to the terminal (precisely, where the STDOUT (FD 1) is currently attached to, presumably terminal), so the errors are being shown
- Then, for `>/dev/null`, the STDOUT is being sent to `/dev/null`, this happens later